# Not able to run oozie workflow in AWS EMR

Tags: hadoop, smtp, amazon-emr, oozie

We are trying to implement a POC where we are trying to run Oozie in AWS EMR.  Due to security reasons, I cannot post the workflow but it is an simple example where we only have an rename action which renames the file name. The rest of the actions are the standard ones like start, end, Fatal error, error Handler etc.
The same workflow worked fine on EC2 instance. But when we try to run Oozie workflow on EMR we are getting the following error

```
2019-09-12 19:34:41,300  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[<hostname>] USER[hadoop] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[<WorkflowName>] JOB[0000006-190911195656052-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000006-190911195656052-oozie-oozi-W@ErrorHandler] Error starting action [ErrorHandler]. ErrorType [ERROR], ErrorCode [EM007], Message [EM007: Encountered an error while sending the email message over SMTP.]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: EM007: Encountered an error while sending the email message over SMTP.
        at org.apache.oozie.action.email.EmailActionExecutor.email(EmailActionExecutor.java:304)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.email.EmailActionExecutor.validateAndMail(EmailActionExecutor.java:173)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.email.EmailActionExecutor.start(EmailActionExecutor.java:112)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:243)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:68)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:291)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.SignalXCommand.execute(SignalXCommand.java:459)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.SignalXCommand.execute(SignalXCommand.java:82)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:291)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionEndXCommand.execute(ActionEndXCommand.java:283)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionEndXCommand.execute(ActionEndXCommand.java:62)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:291)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionCheckXCommand.execute(ActionCheckXCommand.java:244)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionCheckXCommand.execute(ActionCheckXCommand.java:56)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:291)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:210)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: <hostname>, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
```

When we check the application logs, we get the below error

```
Launcher AM execution failed
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the S3FileSystem FileSystem implementation
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2564)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.FSLauncherURIHandler.create(FSLauncherURIHandler.java:36)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PrepareActionsHandler.execute(PrepareActionsHandler.java:86)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PrepareActionsHandler.prepareAction(PrepareActionsHandler.java:73)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.executePrepare(LauncherAM.java:371)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.access$000(LauncherAM.java:55)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM$2.run(LauncherAM.java:220)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.run(LauncherAM.java:217)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM$1.run(LauncherAM.java:153)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.main(LauncherAM.java:141)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the S3FileSystem FileSystem implementation
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2564)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1060)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$RecordCompressWriter.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1371)
```

Hadoop distribution:Amazon 2.8.5
Oozie version:Oozie 5.1.0
EMR version : emr-5.26.0

Appreciate any guidance here.

Comment: Is your code attempting to use a SequenceFile? According to the error, S3 doesn't allow those

Comment: No. We are using a simple .txt file as an input for this sample workflow. We are just trying to rename the file.

Comment: What is the oozie action type?

Comment: It's a java action where we are renaming the files

Comment: The SMTP error is now fixed. We are receiving mails now. But we are still facing the "Unsupported" error.

Comment: S3 doesn't directly support rename. You'd have to copy a file and delete the old one. When you switched to using Oozie and EMR did you also switch to using S3 instead of another file system?

Comment: No. We are still using HDFS and not S3 to store the files. This same exercise worked fine in Ec2 instances.

Comment: Why are you getting the error about S3? "Not implemented by the S3FileSystem FileSystem implementation"

Comment: That's what we are not sure of. We are running the oozie workflow in EMR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after we used the older version of Oozie i.e., 4.3. No other changes made. Works fine. Had read in one of the AWS links that some people were not able to execute oozie with 5.X versions. Will update the answer once we get an concrete reply from AWS.